# XWS Security signing SOAP message with hmac-sha256

Tags: soap, spring-ws, sign, secret-key

I am facing a dilemma with XWS Security.
I have a soap message that I want to sign with HMAC Algorithm.
My policy.xml looks 
`

```
<xwss:Sign includeTimestamp="true" >
    <xwss:X509Token certificateAlias="client"  keyReferenceType="Identifier"
    encodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" />

    <xwss:CanonicalizationMethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" disableInclusivePrefix="true"/>

    <xwss:SignatureMethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256"/>

    <xwss:SignatureTarget type="xpath" value=".//SOAP-ENV:Body">
        <xwss:DigestMethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <xwss:Transform algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" disableInclusivePrefix="true"/>
    </xwss:SignatureTarget>
</xwss:Sign>
`
```

I also have created a JKS file that contains my private keys and certificats.

But When I start signing my message, I got this error:
 `Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: key must be SecretKey 
   at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:400) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:708) ~[xws-security-3.0.jar:3.0-FCS]
        ... 99 common frames omitted`

Almost all the documents that I found in the internet are saying that the SecretKey are only used to Encrypt/Decrypt the message.

Just to make this clear: when I used the RSA algorithm, everything went well.

Can anyone explain to me : why the HMAC is looking for a SecretKey ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue.